# Angular service failing to consume external API

Tags: angular

I'm trying to consume an external API (http://developer.perfectgym.com/api/memberships/memberships/) from an Angular 9 app.

I created a service class (`perfectgym.service.ts`) as follows (simplified):

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Bearer BlAhbLaHblAH'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PerfectgymService {
  private PERFECTGYM_API = "https://demo.perfectgym.pl/Api";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAvailableMemberships() {
     return this.httpClient.get(this.PERFECTGYM_API+'/Memberships/Memberships?timestamp=0', httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Then I use it into my component (`membership.component.ts`) as follows:

```
export class MembershipComponent implements OnInit {
  memberships: any = [];

  constructor(private api: PerfectgymService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.api.getAvailableMemberships().subscribe(data => {
      for (const d of (data as any)) {
        this.memberships.push({
          id: d.id,
          timestamp: d.timestamp,
          name: d.name,
          isActive: d.isActive,
          isDeleted: d.isDeleted
        });
      }
      console.log(this.memberships);
    });
  }
}
```

When a access the page and inspect it's results, on Edge DevTools console I can see an error "HTTP405: BAD METHOD ..." and into network tab, Edge informs that mehtod OPTIONS was used (hence the error, since the service expects a GET).

Since the call is pretty straightforward (`httpClient.get`) I decided to debug it using Chrome. Chrome, instead Edge, show that the request was done using GET, but instead a 405 error, I can see into the console shows the CORS error:

[image]

But, calling the API through the console (curl/Invoke-RestMethod) or SoapUI works. So, the API seems to be working and opened to external calls.

Since I'm new to Angular, I don't know how to solve this issue and any advice is welcome.

Comment: It's a preflight request done by the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Answer (score 1):

> CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a system, consisting of transmitting HTTP headers, that determines whether browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing responses for cross-origin requests. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS)

An angular server that runs on `localhost:4200` by default so if you are using a back-end server that runs on a different domain, you may have CORS issues if your server is not configured properly.

This can be fixed by configuring the server, In case if you need you can try below method to solve the issue.

> Step 1: Create a Proxy Configuration File `src/proxy.conf.json` and add this

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

> Step 2: Add a `proxyConfig` key to `angular.json`  under the `serve->options`

```
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
```

Then Run your Angular App.

> Refrence: https://www.techiediaries.com/fix-cors-with-angular-cli-proxy-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, I'm using Angular/cli Version 13.0.

```
@Injectable()
export class PerfectgymService {
  private PERFECTGYM_API = 'https://demo.perfectgym.pl/Api';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAvailableMemberships() {
     return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.PERFECTGYM_API + '/Memberships/Memberships?timestamp=0');
  }
}
```